# Xcode debugging - displaying images

Tags: xcode, debugging

I love using the Xcode debugger. You can take a look at a variable's value and even change it.

But can I somehow DISPLAY the image that is referenced by an image variable? I know I can see its raw bytes, but it would be much more human-friendly to display a window with its contents.

Xcode might not support this. Maybe there is an external tool that would help display images?

Answer (score 316):

Use **Quick Look** to inspect images in the Xcode debugger.

Select an `NSImage` or `UIImage` in the debugger, then click the Quick Look "eye" icon.

[image: "eye" icon in Xcode debugger toolbar]

Like other areas of OS X, you can also use <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to Quick Look!

[image: Viewing a UIImage in the Xcode debugger via Quick Look]

Quick Look in the debugger can also be implemented for your own classes:

[Enabling Quick Look for Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/CustomClassDisplay_in_QuickLook/CH01-quick_look_for_custom_objects/CH01-quick_look_for_custom_objects.html)

> The variables Quick Look feature in the Xcode debugger allows you to obtain a quick visual assessment of the state of an object variable through a graphical rendering, displayed in a popover window either in the debugger variables view or in place in your source code.
>
> This chapter describes how you implement a Quick Look method for your custom class types so that object variables of those types can also be rendered visually in the Quick Look popover window.

Comment: This is the most valuable answer of the year!

Comment: Ages coding in Xcode and I never knew about this feature! This is awesome!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Knew about this feature but thanks for the spacebar tip! Much easier than clicking the eye with mouse. :)

Comment: you can also select the image object and hit spaceBar

Comment: Work with Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2 like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you like to work with the lldb console, use [chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) command "visualize"

tip:

after the installation, you can set a conditional breakpoint after setting the UIImage with the action:
 "visualize myUIImageToShowWithQuickLook"

[image]

this will show you the image automatically when the debugger stops.

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT:**

As of Xcode 5, the debugger can show you the visual representation of UIImage/CGImageRef variables!

Xcode itself can't do it. I don't know about external tools.

What i'm doing to test images while debugging is to convert that raw data into an image-file format, like .png, and then saving it somewhere, and then i'm opening the image with any image viewing tool.

I have a piece of code for that purpose, which look basically like that:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myUIImage);
[imageData writeToURL:desktopURL atomically:YES];
```

And i'm just copy-pasting this code where i want to see content of an image on the run.

Make sure to get rid of this code as soon as possible due to the high-cost of the conversion of `UIImage` to `NSData`

Comment: just curious: why do you say "(and shouldn't) do it"? there was once a time when people said that computers "shouldn't" have color screens, as they were too expensive, or that a text editor used by programers "shouldn't" syntax check your code. at some point we do need to move on from archaic ideas, surely?

Comment: Ok, so i take the "shouldn't" back. I wish one day IDE's will interpret images while debugging.

Comment: This is a great idea and just helped me - thanks. Kind of obvious once someone points it out, but still a great pointer.

Comment: @unsynchronized will you look at that... Xcode 5 can show images in the debugger...

Answer (score 15):

Edit for Xcode 5: Now when you hover over an image variable name, there is an "eye" icon on the right. Just click it to see the current image!

NOTE: sometimes this fails in Xcode, even if the image is correct. If this happens, OR if you don't have a UIImage variable (e.g. it's a property of another object, you can still use the older answer:

Older answer: Starting with Avraham's answer, I tried a few experiments for displaying an iOS image from lldb without having to recompile or add it to a view.  I finally came up with:

```
e [UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage) writeToFile:@"/Users/<userName>/Desktop/myImage.png" atomically:NO];
```

I keep this string in a text editor and paste it when I need it.  This stores the current image I'm interested in (in this case, "myImage") to a PNG file on the Desktop. Then I can just open this file with Preview.

If you're working on an iOS device, then you can use

```
 e [UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage) writeToFile:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingString:@"/myImage.png"] atomically:NO];
```

Then you can use the Finder; select your device; "Files"; then your dev app, and copy the image to your Desktop to view it.

Comment: +1000000 This is amazing solution! I'd like to add that if you are debugging on the device, you can use something like iFunBox or iExplorer to retrieve the image from the device.

Comment: You can even write directly to "/Users/<your username>/"; this way you won't have to look for your temp folder via GUIDs

Comment: Good suggestion (note you have to use /Users/<your username>/, it doesn't work with ~/ ). Updated the suggestion accordingly.

Comment: Awesome suggestion @mackworth. Thanks.

Comment: this solution is outdated and should not be used, click the EYE icon in the debugger drawer now.

Answer (score 5):

#### What if you can't get to the image via the variables view?

Echoing what @pkamb said - you can use the variables view to quick look at an image. But what if you can't get to the image?

for example I have an image at `(contentViewController.view.subviews[0].subviews[1] as? UIImageView).image`

but if I try to expand `contentViewController` in the variable view it doesn't expose my subviews

[image]

what you can do is right click, add an expression, and then you can see it!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then you should be able to  use the same command as above:   po [UIImagePNGRepresentation((contentViewController.view.subviews[0].subviews[1] as? UIImageView).image) writeToFile:@"/Users/<userName>/Desktop/watchImage.png" atomically:NO];

Answer (score 4):

Click the eye icon when hovering over a variable in Xcode:

[image: Xcode eye icon]

Answer (score -8):

You can put a breakpoint in the line of your image, and then in the debugger, just write:

```
po your_UIImage_object
```

`po` stands for `print object`, it's a GDB command which will display several useful informations about the object passed, in your case the image.

Comment: Actually using po with the UIImage object directly will only print to the console the instance's class name memory address. Something like: <UIImage: 0x7fc98df6c7d0>

Comment: @Daniel what about its size?